# Best way to customize winforms frame?

Tags: c#, winforms, nonclient-area

I would like to draw some simple rectangles and text over the window frame so it looks like Visual Studio. Can it be done or should i make a borderless window and handle moving andresizing myself?

EDIT:
I wrote this. But how do I draw now?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WndProcMsg.WM_PAINT) //0x000f
    {

    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: When I Googled for your title, there were a number of results. Could you update your question with which of this techniques you have already tried?

Comment: [Fancy Windows Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33716/fancy-windows-forms?fid=1536616&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=101). VisualStudio is a WPF application, though (with a few WinForms parts). Not the same thing.

Comment: The standard way since Vista is with DWM (mainly **DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea**)
   A test in C#/Winforms, from MSDN sample : [Custom Caption](https://i.ibb.co/2s7hc5z/Custom-Caption2.jpg) (DirectComposition can also be used, but more complicated...)

Comment: @Castorix link to sample/code?

Comment: I converted/adapted the MS C++ code into C# from : [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe works great.
It was traslated to C# by [@Chris Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314028/chris-taylor). You can download the project from his [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=5BB13275DC6B8248%21162&cid=5BB13275DC6B8248)

Just fix `case Win32Messages.WM_NCHITTEST` with:

```
int ht = NCHitText(m);
if (callDWP) 
{ 
   callDWP = (ht == Win32Constants.HTNOWHERE);
    result = new IntPtr(ht);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the WM_NCPAINT instead:

```
if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT) 
            { 

                IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd); 
                if ((int)hdc != 0) 
                { 
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc); 
                   .... work with graphics
                    ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hdc); 
                } 

            }
```

with the Graphics object you can do all the drawing operation you need. 
As far as I remember, when owner drawing the window you can possibly experience some flickering, in such a case you should consider handling WM_ERASEBACKGROUND and return false.